# jQuery closest() appears to find parent id when there is none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener for when the user clicks in the window. I want to see if the clicked element has any parent element with a certain id. I use the jQuery closest() function for that. But it always returns true.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galivan/x5mdv5p8/) that demonstrates my code.

There must be some major error, because if I change the id from `if($(event.target).closest('#activatemenu'))`
into any other id

```
if($(event.target).closest('#rrrrrrr'))
```

it still returns true.

Code in fiddle:

```js
$(function() {

 $(document).click(function(event) {

    if($(event.target).closest('#activatemenu')) {
        
                $('.wrap').prepend('<p>the clicked element has a parent with the id of activatemenu</p>');
               }else{
                  $('.wrap p').remove();
               }
  
  });


});
```

```css
.stuff{
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:red 2px solid;
}
.otherstuff{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div id="activatemenu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="stuff">
           <p>Here is some text</p>
        </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="otherstuff">
    <p>Other stuff!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two problems with your code.

1. First, you need to search for the closest `activemenu` not `activatemenu`. `activatemenu` does not exist in your code.
2. Second, jQuery will always return an array so you need to check the length to see whether the element was found as a non-empty array will always return `true`.

See below for a working example:

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).click(function(evt) {
        if($(evt.target).closest('#activemenu').length) {
            $('.wrap').prepend('<p>the clicked element has a parent with the id of activemenu</p>');
        } else {
            $('.wrap p').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.stuff {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: red 2px solid;
}

.otherstuff {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="activemenu">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="stuff">
                    <p>Here is some text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="otherstuff">
        <p>Other stuff!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I fixed the "activemenu" typo before I posted, but forgot to save it - I have updated that now. Well explained.

Answer (score 0):

`$(event.target).closest('#activatemenu')` will always return an object so if condition will always be true, better check for `$(event.target).closest('#activatemenu').length`

```js
$(function() {

$(document).click(function(event) {
if($(event.target).closest('#activemenu').length) {

            $('.wrap').prepend('<p>the clicked element has a parent with the id of activemenu</p>');
           }else{
               $('.wrap p').remove();
           }

  });


});
```

```css
.stuff{
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:red 2px solid;
}
.otherstuff{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div id="activemenu">
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="stuff">
       <p>Here is some text</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="otherstuff">
<p>Other stuff!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest always returns a jQuery object which resolves to `truthy`. You need to check the length of the object.

```
$(event.target).closest('#rrrrrrr').length
```

Or, use

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('#activemenu').length) {
      $('.wrap').prepend('<p>the clicked element has a parent with the id of activemenu</p>');
    } else {
      $('.wrap p').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.stuff {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: red 2px solid;
}

.otherstuff {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="activemenu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="stuff">
          <p>Here is some text</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="otherstuff">
    <p>Other stuff!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```